# Lack of activity (new questions are not being listed)

Tags: discussion

Unless there is sometime wrong on my side, today, at some point the newest qustion  *How to Calculate $\pi$ [closed]* was the newest question asked over seven hours ago? At some point the new most active question was over 2 hours ago?

I don't think I have ever seen such little activity in a day. Is something wrong today, or is it just a slow day?

Comment: I posted this question, and it did not appear on the new question page. This is probably why I don't see any new questions.

Comment: Voted to re-open. I don't think that questions like this are "too localized" for the meta site.

Comment: @Carl: +1. But to play devil's advocate, this question will be pretty much useless to anyone two months from now. It's utility has probably *already* expired. Thus, too localized.

Answer (score 10):

This was a side-effect of our database migration. We had to rebuild a few services after it, so things were down for a while.

Should be all good now!

Comment: The various automatic updates (comment notifications, comments, edits, votes, etc.) are still not working consistently: I still have to reload pages manually to get them. The main question page seems to be okay, or mostly so, but the pages for individual questions definitely are not.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hrm. They've been working alright for me, notifications and all, although admittedly on other sites. I'd say give it another day or two. If it's still a problem, please post a new bug report with your browser, OS, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Did a bit of digging - we had issues with realtime updates earlier today. Fingers crossed - should be fine now.

Comment: Thanks very much. I’m also keeping my fingers crossed, but it’s looking much better now.

Comment: Adam, is there any plan to release a new public dump to the data.SE site? The FAQ there says updates are monthly; in reality it is closer to bimonthly; and it has been three months since the last public data dump... Does the aforementioned migration have anything to do with the lack of dumps?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sort of. This database migration is going to make it easier/possible for us to make the Data Explorer up-to-date to (ideally) within a week. Nick Craver posted some details on our goals as well as the issues we're still working on [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145732/155160).